# Firebase emulator incoherent hosts?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-tools

I am using the Firebase emulator to test my code locally, in a NodeJS project. However I need to use inconsistent hosts or it won't work. Has anyone got an idea why?

This is what I mean:

I initialize Firebase Admin as follows

```
    app = admin.initializeApp({
      projectId: projectId,
      databaseURL: `${process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST}?ns=${projectId}`,
      authDomain: `${process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST}?ns=${projectId}`
    })
```

Below are the variants of the environment variables I tested.

When I do this:

```
    process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9000"
    process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9099"
```

It does not work, I get:

```
Error: Error while making request: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:9099. Error code: ECONNREFUSED
```

9099 is the port on which the `Auth` emulator is running

If I replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` as follows:

```
    process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST="127.0.0.1:9000"
    process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST="127.0.0.1:9099"
```

the `Auth` module works, but I get:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
```

When accessing the database on the following line:

```
    const referenceDatabase = admin.database().ref('Locations/10303')
```

However when I put this:

```
    process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9000"
    process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST="127.0.0.1:9099"
```

Everything works.

Why is that? Why do I need `localhost` for the database but `127.0.0.1` for `Auth`?

The installed version of `firebase-admin` is `10.3.0`

Running on Node 18.12.1 on a Mac Studio M1 running MacOS Ventura 13.0.1

Comment: I am facing the same problem where setting the `FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST` to `localhost:9099` is not working as expected. However, when I change it to `127.0.0.1:9099`, it works perfectly fine. Strange...